# How do I find a link to an answer that works like this the triage link?

Tags: support, triage

This is useful when I get a flag disputed

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14303931

How can I find that for a given ANSWER link?

For example this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37929606/295783

Neither of the numbers worked in the triage link

Comment: Only *questions* go through the triage queue, so it won't work for answers. And even with questions, only certain ones go through triage, so there may not even *be* such a link.

Comment: You can find them in the timeline http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37929606/timeline, but as Cody said that's an answer, it had however a [Low Quality Post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12752360) review

Comment: Sorry for getting the review/triage mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, only questions go through triage. Second of all, not all questions go through triage.

Third of all, you can find them in the timeline view.

For your linked answer, that link looks like this: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/37929606/timeline

In general terms, the timeline link looks like this: `https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<post id>/timeline`

In your case, the only review that was completed was a Low Quality post review in June 2016, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12752360) one, it ended in 3x Looks OK and 2x Recommend deletion.

Comment: I was looking for the link you posted  http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12752360 since I was told it was disputed. I do not see my name in your link though...

Comment: @mplungjan In the reviews, it doesn't say "XY's flag was reviewed" it's just a review that acts on all of the flags on a particular answer.

Comment: I meant : my name is not there - I guess it would not be since I was NOT reviewing, my flag was reviewed?  `Review completed Jun 20 '16 at 21:49:
Michael Gaskill reviewed this Jun 20 '16 at 21:49: Looks OK
Warren Dew reviewed this Jun 20 '16 at 21:19: Looks OK
Luke reviewed this Jun 20 '16 at 21:18: Recommend Deletion
JNYRanger reviewed this Jun 20 '16 at 20:19: Recommend Deletion
Qirel reviewed this Jun 20 '16 at 19:25: Looks OK`

Comment: @mplungjan Why would it be there? You just flagged it, you didn't review it.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that now. Thanks